# SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow - Create item with multiple choice field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am trying to use a create item action to create a new item in a list.  The list I am targeting has a column of type Choice with multiple selection (checkboxes) enabled.

When I attempt to enter the value / text of the checkbox I need checked I receive an error in the workflow (HTTP BadRequest). I cannot find how to format the string so that the list will accept it.

I have determined this is the issue, if I remove this item from the create item action it will create the item correctly.

Comment: Do you get an error when you even enter a single value which exactly matches one of the choice values ?

Comment: Yes.  If I enter in the exact text next to the checkbox it will error out when I run the workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine when I test it. Below is how I did to let you compare. Might be a good idea to test it in isolation on your SharePoint to eliminate other potential issues.

1. Create a list called Test
2. Add a new Choice Column, select Checkboxes option, populate them with Choice 1, Choice 2 and Choice 3
3. Create a SPD 2013 workflow for this list
4. Create a New List Item action to set the title to T1, choice field to "Choice 2" (without quotes)
5. Create another New List Item action to set the title to T2, and choice field to "Choice1,Choice2" (no quotes, important to not to leave a space either side of the comma).
6. Create a new list item by hand. Go to that item's workflows and run your new workflow. In my tests this creates two new list items successfully having choice fields set correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I tried creating a new column in the same list with options of: A, B, C.  When I try to populate a new item with the workflow I get the same error when entering "A" in the value... I'm guessing this is an issue with my environment.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Separate the fields with “;#” and no spaces.

Comment: I have no idea why this works but it does - if you use the "set field in current item" and have it return a string (not a choice, comma delimited)
and in that field your choices are separted like so:
[field1];#[field2]